# Print values in Python debugger

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

In my Python code, I have this call inside a bounded method:

```
instances = instance_objects.InstanceList().get_by_host(ctxt, self.host)
```

When I debug with the Python debugger (pdb) and I issue `p instances` i get this output:

```
InstanceList(objects=[Instance(bdfbf658-da32-445d-9560-56d496abcb9d)])
```

When I issue `p instances.objects` i get this output:

```
[Instance(
access_ip_v4=None,
access_ip_v6=None,
architecture=None,
auto_disk_config=False,
availability_zone=None,
cell_name=None,
cleaned=False,
vcpus=1,
)]
```

How can I print out the value of vcpus in pdb?

Comment: Isn't the value 1? It looks like you're getting that data when you issue `p instances.objects`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I would like to have only the value 1 printed out. The thing is that this `Instance` is much longer than what I actually listed. What you see is only a small part of it.

Comment: Btw: is it a dict in a list? Or a tuple in a list?

Comment: Did you try `p instances.objects[0].vcpus`?

Comment: @DavidCullen, I'll give it a go and let you know, thx!

Comment: @DavidCullen, yes that worked. If you wanna put your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Side note: you might want to try ipdb instead of pdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
p instances.objects[0].vcpus
```

Comment: Just a short question: is it a tuple in a list? I mean, it cannot be a dict in a list because a dict has curly brackets. Right?

Comment: It looks like an instance of a class named `Instance`. It looks like `vcpus` is an attribute of the class. What is the output of `p type(instances.objects[0])`?